# Using python scapy to capture network traffic in windows

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers, sniffing

Good morning, everyone,

I am trying to write a script in python that uses scapy to perform packet capture in Windows 11 environment.

The script starts if I use:

`packet = scapy.sniff(iface=None, timeout=duration, filter="tcp")`

but it doesn't log anything.

If I use
`packet = scapy.sniff(iface=if_to_sniff, timeout=duration, filter="tcp")`
instead, I get error on opening the interface.

This is my complete test script.

```
import os
import scapy.all as scapy


def sniff_traffic(filename, duration):
    intrf = scapy.get_if_list()

    intrf_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "documents", unique_code, "intrf.txt")
    with open(intrf_path, "w") as f:
        for item in intrf:
            f.write(f"{item}\n")

    if_to_sniff = scapy.get_if_list()[0]

    writer = scapy.PcapWriter(filename)

    while True:
        packet = scapy.sniff(iface=if_to_sniff, timeout=duration, filter="tcp")
        if packet is None:
            break

        writer.write(packet)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unique_code = "a425c5a1-c788-43db-ae2a-cb9be6e7cc6f"
    pcap_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "documents", unique_code, "packets.pcap")
    intrf_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "documents", unique_code, "intrf.txt")
    duration = 5

    sniff_traffic(pcap_path, duration)
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

How to use Scapy with python on windows 11

Answer (score 0):

The issue you mentioned with `iface=None` may not capture packets because it defaults to the first available network interface. You should specify the network interface you want to capture on explicitly. You can use `scapy.get_if_list()` to see the available interfaces and then select the appropriate one.

You can use `get_if_list()` as you have done to list available interfaces, but make sure you choose the correct one based on your requirements.